# Structuring a project with internal tests for Java 9+ modules

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system

I'm trying to learn how the Java 9+ module system works and I ran into an aspect where my old way of structuring a project no longer works.

What I have done in several projects is that for a test to check if the internals of my class were in the right state I created a package private access to get to that state.
Then my test class would be in the same package and could access this field/method, yet normal users of my class would not be able to get to this.

Following the example provided in [the maven-surefire-plugin documentation for JUnit 5](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/jpms.html#Examples_using_JUnit5) I find that only reflection remains as an option to get to those internal variables for testing.

To me this all feels like I fell down the wrong rabbit hole because of my current lack of knowledge.

I have not been able to find/figure out what the normal/intended way of doing such a common and normally trivial thing.

How do you do this properly?

What is the correct way to structure a maven based java project so the tests can access the internals of my classes?

---

Note I published my attempts here https://github.com/nielsbasjes/learnjavamodules

Following the examples and documentation I have found so far I find myself sliding down this slope:

1. If `main` code is a module then the `test` code also needs to be a module.
2. Each module must have a distinct module name.

   - So the `main` and `test` code lives in different modules
     In the example `com.foo.impl` and `com.foo.test`
3. A single java package may not exist in two modules.

   - So the `main` and `test` code cannot share a package.
   - In the example `com.foo.impl` and `com.foo.implt`.
4. The `package private` trick no longer works because that would need the same package to exist in both my `main` and my `test` modules.
5. Which forces me to open the internals I want to test.

   1. So I either make it fully public (which I do not want).
   2. Or I have to do 'opens' and resort to reflection magic to get to the field.

```
opens nl.basjes.stats 
   to com.esotericsoftware.kryo,
      tests.nl.basjes.jpms.experiment;
```

and in the tests

```
Field sumField = average.getClass().getDeclaredField("sum");
sumField.setAccessible(true);
int sum = (int) sumField.get(average);
assertEquals(10, sum);
```

intstead of just doing

```
assertEquals(10, average.sum);
```

Comment: _So the `main` and `test` code lives in different modules_ They don't have to.

Comment: How do I make that happen?

Comment: `main` and `test` can live only in the same module when that is the `unnamed` module (meaning no module at all) or when both end up in the same jar (meaning you ship the test code with the product). Something you *can* do …  but you shouldn't.

Comment: **maven** and probably also **gradle** have tackled this problem of separating test classes in modular java.

Comment: In my test project I have tried to follow https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/jpms.html (junit 5) yet that does not solve the problem I have.

Comment: `--patch-module` to inject your test classes is the right way.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Do you know of a public project that shows how to do this?

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/nipafx/module-system-woes/tree/main/testing

Answer (score 0):

You can use a module also from code that is not in a module, and currently, JUnit is not modularised. So you write your JUnit tests as usual, with the drawback that you cannot test features that behave different when used by a module. But as these are not internal by definition, this should not harm you much.

For the API tests (the public stuff), you create a new project with a separate module, and wrote your tests there. Currently, I do not JUnit for these tests.